# Double substitution in one line in bash script

Tags: bash, substitution

I want to change extension of a file path and turn it into a full path.
removing the first . and then the extension, adding new extension and current directory path.

something like this but I get a substitution error.

```
echo `pwd` $(echo ${${FILENAME#?}%.*}".spindens.cube")
```

I know I can do this by two different substitution steps, I was just going to learn from this community to code cleaner.

Thanks
in advance

Comment: aside: You can do `echo "$PWD"` instead of `echo $(pwd)`. It's cleaner and doesn't involve a subshell.

Comment: Wouldn't basename be the tool for that task?

Comment: basename will remove the path, ./abx/abc.out -> abc.out not /abx/abc.out